# Data encryption with python

Tags: python, strings, python-2.x, cryptography

I am just trying to solve one of the puzzle which is explained below:

> The sentence `if man was meant to stay on the ground god would have
>   given us roots` after removing spaces is 54 characters long, so it is
>   written in the form of a grid with 7 rows and 8 columns.
>
> The encoded message is obtained by displaying the characters in a
>   column, inserting a space, and then displaying the next column and
>   inserting a space, and so on. For example, the encoded message for the
>   above rectangle is:
>
> ```
> imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghn sseoau
> ```

For more conditions please refer [here:](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/encryption/problem)

```
from math import ceil, sqrt
from string import whitespace

def encrypt(string):
    enc_string = string.translate(None,whitespace)
    length = len(enc_string)

    #calculate the no of colums for the grid
    columns = int(ceil(sqrt(length)))

    #form a list of strings each of length equal to columns
    split_string = [enc_string[i:i+columns] for i in range(0, len(enc_string), columns)]

    #encrypted list of strings
    new_string = []
    for string in split_string:

        for i in range(len(string)):
            try:
                #replace the element in the list with the new string
                new_string[i] = new_string[i].replace(new_string[i], new_string[i] + string[i])
            except IndexError:
                #exception indicates that the string needs be added with new Index
                new_string.append(string[i])

    return " ".join(new_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = raw_input().strip()
    result = encrypt(s)
    print(result)
```

Please help me if multiple for loops can be avoided and any other improvements.

Comment: Can you add, in the description, what are the rules to compute the lengths of the rectangle and how "missing" values at the end should be handled?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger: have provided the link to refer for more information, didn't get wt "missing" values you are talking about ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That seems like a very long method to splice and put together the string every even set of characters. You are essentially trying to build a square matrix using the characters from the given string. Python has a very nice slice-and-stride feature which can perform the same task in a single inline operation.

I took the liberty of rewriting your `encrypt` function:

```
from math import ceil
from string import whitespace

def square_encrypt(str_input): # avoiding the name `string` as python has a module `string`
    str_input = str_input.translate(None, whitespace) # making a copy and overwriting input parameter
    square_size = int(ceil(len(str_input)**0.5)) # or int(ceil(sqrt(len(str_input))))
    encrypted_list = [str_input[i::square_size] for i in xrange(square_size)]
    return " ".join(encrypted_list)
```

Comment: You're already pulling in math.ceil, so why raise to the power `0.5` instead of use math.sqrt?  For efficiency?

Comment: @RonJohn I copied over the code from my terminal; where I had not imported `sqrt`. The performance is very slightly different between the two. Though, using `sqrt` is more readable. :)

Comment: can you mention the reason for using "xrange" over "range"? I refered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x. I didn't get the meaning "xrange is a sequence object that evaluates lazily". If possible could you explain this.

Comment: @Here_2_learn The official documentation explains it better https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/functions#xrange

Answer (score 12):

One of your lines of code is horribly cryptic. I think it's so bad it's worthy of it's own answer.

> ```
> new_string[i] = new_string[i].replace(new_string[i], new_string[i] + string[i])
> ```

This is a longwinded way of writing:

```
new_string[i] += string[i]
```

This is something you should have noticed, and should have gone to first.

---

If you change your `for` loop to use `enumerate` too, then the above line becomes much cleaner.

```
for i, char in enumerate(string):
    try:
        new_string[i] += char
    except IndexError:
        new_string.append(char)
```

You can also get rid of the `try`, if you fill your `new_string` with empty strings, on creation.

```
new_string = ['']*columns
for string in split_string:
    for i, char in enumerate(string):
        new_string[i] += char
```

---

However hjpotter92's answer is still what you should do.

Comment: Really cool improvements, and Thanks for being frank "horribly cryptic"